# Floating Point always returns 0

Tags: assembly, floating-point, nasm

I'm trying to wrestle with floating points in NASM, and I just can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. This program always gives me back 0.000000, and I really can't see where an error could be.

```
extern printf
extern scanf

SECTION .data
junk: dq 7.6
temp: dq 0
print_float: db "%f",10,0
SECTION .bss

SECTION .text

global main
main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp

    finit

    fld qword[junk]
    fst qword[junk]

    push dword [junk-4]
    push dword [junk]
    push dword print_float
    call printf
    add esp,12  

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp 
    mov eax,0
    ret
```

Comment: `push dword [junk+4]`! Plus! Plus!

Comment: I am now heavily embarrassed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You only need one of `add esp,12` or `mov esp, ebp` to restore `esp` to where you pushed the caller's `ebp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to rkhb for the answer to this one.

```
push dword[junk+4]
```

Is what should be here, rather than the minus.

Comment: If you have the float in an x87 register already, you could do a single 64b store to the stack.  `sub esp, 8` / `fstp [esp]`.  Note that your code leaves `st(0)` occupied on entry to `printf`, which violates the ABI, because you use `fst` not `fstp`.  The FP stack should be empty on function entry.  You don't have a problem because `printf` doesn't try to push 8 floats into the x87 stack registers, but in theory you could.